Frame with Scrollbar in Tkinter?
So I am trying to make a frame and fill it up with data from my database. Only thing is, I need the whole frame to be scrollable. I followed the instructions I saw online and also checked Stackoverflow and I can't find what is wrong with my code. It does not display a scrollbar anywhere on the frame when I run the program.
showWindow = Tk()
showWindow.title("Product List")
showWindow.geometry("500x250")
Main_Frame = Frame(showWindow)
Main_Frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=TRUE)
CanvasA = Canvas(Main_Frame)
CanvasA.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=TRUE)
ProductScroller = Scrollbar(Main_Frame,orient=VERTICAL,
                command= CanvasA.yview)
ProductScroller.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
CanvasA.configure(yscrollcommand=ProductScroller.set)
CanvasA.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: CanvasA.configure(scrollregion=CanvasA.bbox("all")))
InsideFrame = Frame(CanvasA)
CanvasA.create_window((0,0),window= InsideFrame, anchor= "center")

conn = sqlite3.connect('Database')
C = conn.cursor()
C.execute("Select *, oid from Database")
ProductRecords = C.fetchall()
HEADER = LabelFrame(InsideFrame)
HEADER.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, expand=TRUE)
NameH = Label(HEADER, text="Name")
NameH.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)
CostH = Label(HEADER, text="Cost")
CostH.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)
PriceH = Label(HEADER, text="Price")
PriceH.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)
RetailH = Label(HEADER, text="Retail")
RetailH.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)
for record in ProductRecords:
    NewRow= LabelFrame(InsideFrame)
    NewRow.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill = X, expand= TRUE)
    NameR = Label(NewRow,text=record[0])
    NameR.pack(side=LEFT,fill=X,expand=TRUE)
    CostR = Label(NewRow, text=record[1])
    CostR.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=TRUE)
    PriceR = Label(NewRow, text=record[2])
    PriceR.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=TRUE)
    PriceR = Label(NewRow, text=record[3])
    PriceR.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=TRUE)

conn.commit()
conn.close()


You need to set side=LEFT in CanvasA.pack(...).
Also <Configure> should be bound on InsideFrame instead of CanvasA because scrollregion of canvas should be updated when the internal frame is resized.
...
CanvasA.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH,expand=TRUE)
...
#CanvasA.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: CanvasA.configure(scrollregion=CanvasA.bbox("all")))
...
# bind <Configure> on InsideFrame
InsideFrame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: CanvasA.configure(scrollregion=CanvasA.bbox("all")))
CanvasA.create_window((0,0),window= InsideFrame, anchor= "nw") # use "nw" instead of "center"
...

